# I think I don't understand git branches

Tags: git, bitbucket

Salutations everyone,

I have been working on a bash script as a small summer project to learn more about UNIX scripting and on using git.

This has been the first time that I have used branches in git, normally I just stick to master.

I was viewing the git log with the graph (`git log --graph`) when I noticed that my 'develop' branch seemed to have merged with 'master'. Something like this:

```
master   ----1--------3----4----5----6----HEAD
develop      \---2---/
```

but commits 3 onwards were done within the develop branch. Doing `git checkout master` and `git checkout develop` showed this to be true.

What exactly is going on? Is this what is known as fast-forwarding?

**UPDATE #1:**

Commit 1, isn't actually the first commit in my repo, its the last commit I made on 'master'

**UPDATE #2:**

This is the graph as given in `gitk --all`

```
                   Tag '1.0-0'
                        |
master    --*--*--*--*--*--*----2\
develop                     \1----3----4----5----6
```

**UPDATE #3:**

I have had a closer look at `gitk` and have discovered that all commits up until commit 1 happened both in the 'develop' branch as well as the 'master' branch.

Thanks to SimoneDemoGentili for pointing out my incorrect use of `git checkout develop`

P.S.: Commits 1 and 2 are also a mystery to me being that commit 2 is actually an amendment of commit 1 (as far I thought, I used this [advice](http://nathanhoad.net/git-amend-your-last-commit))

Comment: This was your sequence?

* git checkout develop
* git add .
* git commit -m '...'

* git checkout master
* git add .
* git commit -m '...'

Comment: Your commit 3 seems to be indeed the result of a merge... ? Note that your branches actually point to a commit (likely commit 3 is you master, and HEAD is your develop branch), so writing them like you do is misleading. Your commits 1 and 2 are actually in both branches. `$ gitk --all` should help you understand how your branches look like. Also, fast-forwarding does not involve diverging branches like this, only to a branch catching up with another.

Comment: @SimoneDemoGentili: No, it wasn't. It was * git checkout develop * git add . * git commit -m "..." * repeat...

commit 1, isn't actually the first commit in my repo, its the last commit I made on master (plus it has a tag of '1.0-0')
I have amended my question to reflect this

Comment: "git checkout develop" do not create a branch. "git checkout -b develop" create and checkout develop branch.

Have you created deveolp branch before checkout in it?

Comment: @SimoneDemoGentili: No I did not, I simply did `git branch develop`

Comment: And what if you run command "git branch"? I think you do not have develop branch

Comment: @SimoneDemoGentili:
$ git branch
{* develop}
{  master}

Comment: I had a look at `gitk` and it seems that this might have caused the issue that I am experiencing. It seems that all my commits up to the point where I actually branched `git checkout develop; git add .; git commit -m ""; git push origin develop` are within both branches...

Comment: You say that all commits up to 1 happened in both the development branch and the master branch.  That'd be *really* difficult to happen.  What likely happened is they were fast-forward merged.  You might show us the output of `git reflog` - that would tell us most of the story of what happened.

Comment: @wadesworld: I have decided ask that in a different stack [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157479/how-does-one-split-a-branch-from-master).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Branches

A git branch is only a movable pointer to a specific commit. The commits them selfs do not have any branch property attached to them. Git displays a commit to belong to a branch, if the commit is an ancestor of a commit where the branch pointer is attached to.

Say you have the following history:

```
     4 <- A
     |\
     | \
     2  3 <- B
     | /
     |/
     1
     |
     0
```

Then all commits are on branch A, since all commits are ancestors of commit 4, where branch A points to. But only 0, 1 and 3 are on branch B, since these commits are the history of commit 3.

### Fast forward

Fast forward merges are merges, where the branch pointer of one branch can be simply moved to the new commit without loosing history. This is the case, when the target commit is a successor of the commit where the branch currently points to. In the previous example branch A can be FF-Merged onto branch B, since commit 4 is a successor of commit 3. After this merge B would also like A point to commit 4. The following history shows an example of a non-FF merge:

```
A -> 2  3 <- B
     | /
     |/
     1
     |
     0
```

Here B can't be moved to commit 2, since then commit 3 would fall out of the history. To solve this, a real merge between 2 and 3 must be created, leading to the following history:

```
     4 <- B
     |\
     | \
A -> 2  3
     | /
     |/
     1
     |
     0
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a more clear explanation then the one given in the git docs.