# How does one split a branch from master

Tags: git, version-control

Salutations everyone,

I have a somewhat strange problem with my repo. Initial I only had the *master* branch to commit to, however after I completed a functional version of my application I decided to create a *develop* branch to continue developing but leave the working version untouched in *master* until I felt like merging it.

Currently (using `gitk --all`) my git log graph looks like this:

```
                             tag 
                              |
*----*-----*-----*-----*------*------*------*         master & develop
                                     \       \
                                      --------*----*  develop (HEAD)
```

I am unsure as to what I did to cause this, below are the steps I took to creating the *develop* branch:

```
$ git checkout develop
$ vim example.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "first file in develop"
$ git push origin develop
```

After this I countinued on the develop branch until I took a look at *gitk*.

What I want (and think to be the correct/health way of using git branches) is:

```
                            tag
                             |      
*----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*               master
                                    \
                                     *-----*-----* develop (HEAD)
```

What do I need to do to get my repo to look similar to the diagram above?

**EDIT #1:**

Output from `git reflog` for *develop*:

```
54d8daf HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD@{15}
45dcaa7 HEAD@{1}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/develop
45dcaa7 HEAD@{2}: rebase: added another sanity check for cli parameters
f3b0f8b HEAD@{3}: rebase: I am working on getting the console improved, this including better color, and more cammand options
8c48bab HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from develop to 8c48babb10ec2f8f28f364ce57b5095cb080c133^0
54d8daf HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from master to develop
8c48bab HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from develop to master
54d8daf HEAD@{7}: rebase: aborting
3bf3f64 HEAD@{8}: commit: rebase
6aa82d8 HEAD@{9}: rebase: added another sanity check for cli parameters
a9be651 HEAD@{10}: rebase: I am working on getting the console improved, this including better color, and more cammand options
8c48bab HEAD@{11}: checkout: moving from develop to 8c48babb10ec2f8f28f364ce57b5095cb080c133^0
54d8daf HEAD@{12}: rebase: aborting
7890b76 HEAD@{13}: rebase: added another sanity check for cli parameters
46847d7 HEAD@{14}: rebase: I am working on getting the console improved, this including better color, and more cammand options
8c48bab HEAD@{15}: checkout: moving from develop to 8c48babb10ec2f8f28f364ce57b5095cb080c133^0
54d8daf HEAD@{16}: commit: changed the how function, it seems I was right, wc counts all lines regardless of readable symbols or not.
13d35ed HEAD@{17}: commit: am working on the how function (should be trivial, but I have a bad feeling)
852fb68 HEAD@{18}: commit: I have added some more commands (thought not fully implemented), but more specifically I have changed the pattern matching
33dfc9f HEAD@{19}: commit (merge): change some output settings, asthetics and such. I am working on getting more command options for list previous lin
a248465 HEAD@{20}: commit (amend): added another sanity check for cli parameters
f0ca508 HEAD@{21}: commit (amend): added another sanity check for cli parameters
9e24e91 HEAD@{22}: commit: added another sanity check for cli parameters
0194cab HEAD@{23}: commit: I am working on getting the console improved, this including better color, and more cammand options
8c48bab HEAD@{24}: checkout: moving from master to testing
8c48bab HEAD@{25}: commit: I think I have wroked out all of the import bugs, the rest is really just esthetics, welcome version 1
b306d9f HEAD@{26}: commit: as it turns out it was easier then I thought, plus I fixed an incorrect append method
8445a25 HEAD@{27}: commit: seems I miss understood how bash case statments handles regex, or should I say pathname expansion matching
9fc5132 HEAD@{28}: commit: lol, totally forgot to use the function 'run' to get things going
ee2a2c7 HEAD@{29}: commit: seems I haven't yet figured out how to correctly parse cli args...
bb0fd28 HEAD@{30}: commit: fixed incorrect sanity check
eb3db1d HEAD@{31}: commit: have reached a stage I could refer to a working test system, which is what I am going to do.
4bfd53b HEAD@{32}: commit: added a lot more colours (am using a list from arch-wikis), incorporated much better error handling
2d9b598 HEAD@{33}: commit: getting there part 1
0edfcae HEAD@{34}: commit: output functions so far
06130a7 HEAD@{35}: commit: modularized two printing function into a seperate script
e0033b8 HEAD@{36}: commit (initial): used some functions from previous bash script, maybe I should create a generic script for text output...?
```

In error, I tried to do a rebase, which failed on every merge attempt. Using `git diff` on different checkouts of files (`--theirs` and `--ours`) showed no difference between remote and local. So I reset head back to commit `HEAD@{15}`.

**EDIT #2:**
I am sorry for the confusion I might have caused, however in diagram 1, 'master & develop' indicate that both branches (*master* and *develop*) are combined into a single 'stream'. I hope that makes more sense.

**EDIT #3:**

Output from `git log master --pretty=oneline`

```
8c48babb10ec2f8f28f364ce57b5095cb080c133 I think I have wroked out all of the import bugs, the rest is really just esthetics, welcome version 1
b306d9f58c3ebab03364c4381754bc87db9e7f2d as it turns out it was easier then I thought, plus I fixed an incorrect append method
8445a258fc388eba5b920de57b1f390623da87a0 seems I miss understood how bash case statments handles regex, or should I say pathname expansion matching
9fc5132c30bdf2ab143ad046493326ba63e4300d lol, totally forgot to use the function 'run' to get things going
ee2a2c7ff69498a80e9fc5f36cc340f6e1b95bcb seems I haven't yet figured out how to correctly parse cli args...
bb0fd28c89a0c16c379774b7fc5768a4160d6852 fixed incorrect sanity check
eb3db1d055b45793fb9a3fd5f884926687f7b8dd have reached a stage I could refer to a working test system, which is what I am going to do.
4bfd53b3af85d82aea11871a0ddb7f9d583cfb73 added a lot more colours (am using a list from arch-wikis), incorporated much better error handling
2d9b598d77e2b62611dfd2e42b183d0262880014 getting there part 1
0edfcae88e6eae66de4fae1788433d83b90a1c37 output functions so far
06130a7288ce26b4a2235864f7cd5b48a35dcea6 modularized two printing function into a seperate script
e0033b8f440f2ffb7b9a120f5a9be9ea167e1e30 used some functions from previous bash script, maybe I should create a generic script for text output...?
```

Output for `git log develop --pretty=oneline`

```
54d8daf475a5e1108cd6345850245db2d0e6fd80 changed the how function, it seems I was right, wc counts all lines regardless of readable symbols or not.
13d35ed979de3518eca26961f3be4bb0b7d8de03 am working on the how function (should be trivial, but I have a bad feeling)
852fb68b8ca929e1156e38e2a58a12f07bd9aaa5 I have added some more commands (thought not fully implemented), but more specifically I have changed the pat
33dfc9f187a54dc7234c9ca31bee91eef7c89a98 change some output settings, asthetics and such. I am working on getting more command options for list previo
a2484654eff741f4c625f8cb097fbb92f6ac8b9b added another sanity check for cli parameters
9e24e9157157f128f75b3d7859875d06d33137bd added another sanity check for cli parameters
0194cab8af66656bb9fe83c919409354f6d12edc I am working on getting the console improved, this including better color, and more cammand options
8c48babb10ec2f8f28f364ce57b5095cb080c133 I think I have wroked out all of the import bugs, the rest is really just esthetics, welcome version 1
b306d9f58c3ebab03364c4381754bc87db9e7f2d as it turns out it was easier then I thought, plus I fixed an incorrect append method
8445a258fc388eba5b920de57b1f390623da87a0 seems I miss understood how bash case statments handles regex, or should I say pathname expansion matching
9fc5132c30bdf2ab143ad046493326ba63e4300d lol, totally forgot to use the function 'run' to get things going
ee2a2c7ff69498a80e9fc5f36cc340f6e1b95bcb seems I haven't yet figured out how to correctly parse cli args...
bb0fd28c89a0c16c379774b7fc5768a4160d6852 fixed incorrect sanity check
eb3db1d055b45793fb9a3fd5f884926687f7b8dd have reached a stage I could refer to a working test system, which is what I am going to do.
4bfd53b3af85d82aea11871a0ddb7f9d583cfb73 added a lot more colours (am using a list from arch-wikis), incorporated much better error handling
2d9b598d77e2b62611dfd2e42b183d0262880014 getting there part 1
0edfcae88e6eae66de4fae1788433d83b90a1c37 output functions so far
06130a7288ce26b4a2235864f7cd5b48a35dcea6 modularized two printing function into a seperate script
e0033b8f440f2ffb7b9a120f5a9be9ea167e1e30 used some functions from previous bash script, maybe I should create a generic script for text output...?
```

Output for `git log master...develop`

```
commit 54d8daf475a5e1108cd6345850245db2d0e6fd80
Author: Hans 
Date:   Thu Jun 21 21:27:14 2012 +0200

    changed the how function, it seems I was right, wc counts all lines regardless of readable symbols or not.

commit 13d35ed979de3518eca26961f3be4bb0b7d8de03
Author: Hans 
Date:   Thu Jun 21 21:09:44 2012 +0200

    am working on the how function (should be trivial, but I have a bad feeling)

commit 852fb68b8ca929e1156e38e2a58a12f07bd9aaa5
Author: Hans 
Date:   Thu Jun 21 20:58:16 2012 +0200

    I have added some more commands (thought not fully implemented), but more specifically I have changed the pattern matching slightly, it is now a r

commit 33dfc9f187a54dc7234c9ca31bee91eef7c89a98
Merge: a248465 9e24e91
Author: Hans 
Date:   Thu Jun 21 20:42:56 2012 +0200

    change some output settings, asthetics and such. I am working on getting more command options for list previous lines and such

commit a2484654eff741f4c625f8cb097fbb92f6ac8b9b
Author: Hans 
Date:   Thu Jun 21 20:23:52 2012 +0200

    added another sanity check for cli parameters

commit 9e24e9157157f128f75b3d7859875d06d33137bd
Author: Hans 
Date:   Thu Jun 21 20:23:52 2012 +0200

    added another sanity check for cli parameters

commit 0194cab8af66656bb9fe83c919409354f6d12edc
Author: Hans 
Date:   Thu Jun 21 20:06:02 2012 +0200

    I am working on getting the console improved, this including better color, and more cammand options
```

Comment: What does it mean when it says "`master & develop`" on the top branch?

Comment: @vergenzt: I mean to say that the branches _master_ and _develop_ are a single branch up until just after the tag. This was not the case when I first created the repo and only had _master_.

Comment: What version of git is in use?

Comment: @wadesworld: git version 1.7.10.msysgit.1 locally, the server is using 1.7.10.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I misunderstood how branches work in git. This was **the** fundamental problem. ***There was no problem at all with how my repo is setup***.

However as Alexander pointed out to me, there is an abnormal merge of `a248465 9e24e91`, thus creating this 'double commit' shown in diagram 1. These commits are actually the same commit but with different SHA1 hashes. I believe this was caused to due to me having incorrectly applied a `git commit --amend`.

The solution to remove them was to rebase the *develop* branch and remove commit `9e24e91` from the history.

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflog: `git reflog` for any branch to look at history for that ref and then just make `git reset --hard HEAD@{INDEX_HERE}` to revert changes for that branch.

First diagram is show a situation when you have made a commit in the master branch and then made a `git pull` inside develop branch. `git pull` will merge tracking branch (master) into the current one (develop).

If you can publish your reflog for branches master and develop then we can check it.

Comment: Yes, there is a merge as expected: `33dfc9f HEAD@{20}: commit (merge): change some output settings,...` is it from `master` branch?

Comment: Reflog is one for all branches :) You shouldn't post it twice for each branch )

Comment: Thanks for that, removed it ;)

Comment: Please add the output for following commands: `git log master --pretty=oneline`, `git log develop --pretty=oneline`, `git log master...develop`

Comment: Ok, according to the git log, your diagram should be the same with diagram 2. But how did you make a merge of two commits from the same branch??? `Merge: a248465 9e24e91` It's abnormal.. I suggest you to make an interactive rebase for develop branch and amend merge commit in the history

Answer (score 1):

> > What do I need to do to get my repo to look similar to the diagram above?

To create the branch 'develop' from 'master', I would follow the instructions given in the [git manual](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging): "To create a branch and switch to it at the same time, you can run the git checkout command with the -b switch".

In your case, Hans, you could do the following (assuming 'master' is in the remote 'origin'):

```
# checkout and pull latest from master
git checkout master
git fetch origin
git pull origin master

# create the develop branch
git checkout -b develop
```

Now the 'master' and 'develop' branches are distinct and future commits should make your commit history look like the correct/healthy diagram that you want to achieve.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I create new repo with my current files, this time however with the correct steps taken to create the _develop_ branch?

Comment: I think that it will be better to understand the situation and fix it, however you can easily delete the `develop` branch and recreate it from the `master` branch again - it's ok, because you haven't publish you develop branch to the remote yet.